# GWT CSS Resource to find all classes

Tags: java, css, gwt, parsing

What i want to do is:

I have css file read from a file into a String. I would like to build some kind of css resource (CssResource ?) out of that string or file, and I'd like to be able to extract from it all classes and id selectors in some kind of collection which i could search.

Does anybody know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a CSS Parser. You can use a SAC compliant parser like [CssParser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/). GWT internally uses a modified version of [Flute](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/). You could go with either of them, though I think CSSParser is better maintained.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple example on how to do this